# Some API and JMeter jobs run twice in a day at times in Jenkins versus once a day

Tags: api, jenkins, jmeter

I have 9 jobs in Jenkins scheduled to run daily at midnight. 1 job for API tests, rest 8 r for JMeter tests. I have set up to receive email with report after each run. On some days, for some jobs, I see that they ran twice. So far I saw 5 same jobs ran twice. I observed on 2 recent days. Schedule is @midnight, build periodically with parameters. How can I ensure jobs run only once as expected?

I reviewed jobs, saw their reports, runs. I am expecting only one run for a job a day versus 2 runs.

Answer (score -1):

We cannot answer your question without seeing job outputs, especially what triggered the job and the job start time. Check your jobs and [jenkins logs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/viewing-logs/) and look for that information.

Maybe there is a problem with this `@midnight` macro especially when it comes to [daylight saving time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) changes , you might want to change your cron expression to something like `1 0 * * *` so it would run 1 minute past midnight.

More information:

- [How to Schedule a Jenkins Job: A Simple Guide](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/how-to-schedule-a-jenkins-job)
- [The Complete Guide to Continuous Integration With Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-jenkins)